# Wordpress no edit media button. nasty bug

Tags: wordpress

I have a really nasty bug.

Edit Image button is not showing when i go on edit image.

However, when i add a gallery mark an image, on the right side bellow the image i can access the edit image screen with crop , resize , rotate tools working.

However when i try to crop / resize/ rotate img, none of the changes are saved.

I tried :

```
      define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false );
      define('SCRIPT_DEBUG', true);
```

Site is big, 50 k visits a day, lots of plugins, 250 mb db. Its a problem for me to reinstall wp and shut down plugins one by one, is there a way of debuging this or does anyone knows a solution to this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To debug a live site, enable `WP_DEBUG` to dump the errors in the file `wp-content/debug.log`. See [Debugging in WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress). There are helper plugins listed in the page, and I recently [made one](https://github.com/brasofilo/view-debug-log) to view the debug file in the dashboard.

But, being the Media button, a JavaScript issue is probable. What Firebug or Chrome tools tell you? Maybe the new jQuery version bugged the theme or a plugin. Maybe you can disable all non-essential plugins.

To fix it, if you can't pin-point the culprit at first, you'll have to make a clone of the site and test freely in another machine.

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding i had this Javascript error, but i did something and now its gone, i think it was due to concatenate script and flusing my browser : ReferenceError: switchEditors is not defined
switchEditors.switchto(this);

post.p...onclick (line 2)
ReferenceError: switchEditors is not defined

switchEditors.switchto(this);

post.p...onclick (line 2) this is basically copypaste of that old error, i will try to debug as you said, and report on progress, thanks!